# dynamic programming, two player matrix game

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

I am programming a matrix game which is played by two player. The objective is to say whether player 1 can win the game return 1, if not return 0.
player can delete either the last row or the last column of the matrix, but only if the sum of the numbers in that row/column is even. example:

```
original matrix: 
[1 2]
[2 2]

then we can subtract these matrices from this:

sum row, and this becomes:
[1 3]                [0 0]
[2 4]                [1 1]

sum col, and this becomes:
[1 2]                [0 1]
[3 4]                [0 1]
```

now we can play the game, and its clear that player 1 can remove from either the row or the column matrix. then player two can make a move, and finally we can see that player 1 cant win in this example.

here is my implementation for this program:

I only provide the method that is suppose to use the row and the column matrices and should return a 1 if player 1 wins and a 0 if player 1 ant win.

```
public static int play(int[][] rowM, int[][] colM){
        int player = 1;
        int[][] matrix = new int[rowM.length][colM[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowM.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < colM[0].length; j++) {
                //if no possible move
                if(rowM[i][j] == 0 && colM[i][j] == 0){
                    //if player 1 is playing, and losing
                    if(player % 2 == 1){
                        matrix[i][j] = 0;
                        player++;
                    }
                    //player 2 is losing
                    else{
                        matrix[i][j] = 1;
                        player++;
                    }
                    continue;
                }

                //if player 1 is playing
                if(player % 2 == 1){
                    player++;
                    //the value in this position is even
                    if(rowM[i][j] == 1){
                        //if there is only 1 row left, 
                        if(i == 0){
                            matrix[i][j] = 1;
                        }
                        else if(matrix[i-1][j] == 1){
                            matrix[i][j] = 1;
                        }
                        else{
                            matrix[i][j] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    //the value in the col matrix this position is even
                    else if(colM[i][j] == 1){
                        //if there is only 1 column left, 
                        if(j == 0){
                            //matrix[i][j] = 1;
                            matrix[i][j] = 1;
                            //player++;
                        }
                        else if (matrix[i][j-1] == 1){
                            matrix[i][j] = 1;
                        }
                        else{
                            matrix[i][j] = 0;
                        }
                    }

                }
                //player 2 is playing
                else{
                    player++;
                    //the value in this position is even
                    if(rowM[i][j] == 1){
                        if(i == 0){
                            matrix[i][j] = 1;
                        }
                        else if(matrix[i-1][j] == 1){
                            matrix[i][j] = 0;
                        }
                        else{
                            matrix[i][j] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    //the value in the col matrix this position is even
                    else if(colM[i][j] == 1){
                        if(j == 0){
                            matrix[i][j] = 1;
                        }
                        else if(matrix[i][j-1] == 1){
                            matrix[i][j] = 0;
                        }
                        else{
                            matrix[i][j] = 1;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
    }
    return matrix[rowM.length-1][colM[0].length-1];
    }
```

rowM and colM are matrices which have 1's and 0's inside, them, I didnt put my method that makes those matrices. this algorithm works with almost everything but I have found few examples that wont work with my implementation. I think some where in my code, specially one of the if statements must not be correct. I use debug to find it but I couldnt find out why it goes wrong.

here is an example that  wot work with my code:

```
a matrix 2*1:
[2]
[1]
```

this gives me a 1, but its wrong it should be 0. Can some one help me to find my problem. this is my last option to see what  am doing wrong. Please help

[image]

Comment: How is this question different from [your last question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817432/what-is-wrong-with-my-implementation-of-a-matrix-game-played-by-two-people)? I think you need to re-read the comments there about how to solve the problem (break things up into small pieces, test each piece).

Comment: I made it smaller. that one was bigger, and had more code and explanation so made it readable.

Comment: @ S. N: To improve a question, *edit* the question, don't repost it. (There's an "edit" link near the bottom.) But I think the other suggestions you were given are going to be more helpful than trying to shoehorn this question into SO's format.

Comment: @S.N I spent some time trying to understand the rules of the game, but still clueless. Could you please give step-by-step operations performed by each player on original matrix ? Or give better explanations to the game rules ?

Comment: @kiruwka please see my example. its in the form of a picture. if you still didnt understand it u can ask me more questions.

Comment: @S.N I don't understand 1. how row and column matrices are created. 2. Why these 2 matrices(rowmatrix, columnmatrix) are needed (you rule says that players remove row/column from original matrix, no ?

Comment: @kiruwka here is my complete code: http://pastebin.com/C71JtC7q                  the removing is done with rowM and colM, these matrices have 0 and 1 inside them, 1 if that number is even and 0 if not. please see method creatematrices.

Comment: @S.N Its not about code. It is that I can not get the idea of the rules. Lets start from the beginning. You have 2 players and one matrix. First player removes last row, so matrix became [1 2], then second player removes last column so matrix become [1]. Now, who wins ?

Comment: @kiruwka its not like that, at first you need to determine the sum of all element in the original matrix in each row and each column, if that sum is even then in the row matrix or in the col matrix we put 1 in that position and otherwise 0. so we have [1 2], if u want to make the row matrix it becomes [0 0], since 1 is not even so a 0 i its place in the row matrix and 1+2 = 3 not even so another 0 in that place. for col its [0 1] since 1 is not even , and 2 is even. the numbers are summed up cumulatively.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44066/discussion-between-kiruwka-and-s-n)